# How to use Ni Mate in blender 2.91

Tags: animation, armature, motion-capture

I want to retarget the Ni Mate armature to my own armature to record a motion capture animation live.

According to the instructions of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nN0neRp444 the settings should be in profile => OSC data  but I can not find it. It may be somewhere else after many years of updates(the tutorial was made on 2012)but I have spent hours looking for it and can’t find it.

Can anybody tell me where are this settings nowadays or does anybody knows any updated tutorial about it?

Thanks in advance.